# fgrep not counting line with accented letter in it

Tags: grep

The chances that I found a bug in fgrep are rather small, so my bet is that I missunderstand something. I was counting the number of addresses in a VCF file with

```
fgrep FN: Contacts.vcf| wc -l
```

to quickly find the number of NV (full name) fields.
I noticed that I lacked one compared to the count in my nextcloud adress book.
I tracked it down to the line of a friend called Jurriën.
If I keep his name fgrep doesn't count the line

```
FN:Jurriën Somelastname
```

If I remove the ë fgrep counts the line.

```
FN:Jurrin Somelastname
```

This is a simple DOS style encoded textfile, straight out of the Nextcloud server.
However fgrep sees it as a binary. so `fgrep -a` works. Is this the expected behaviour?

Comment: It depends on the version of grep. Especially older grep versions flag files/lines with a 0x80-0xff byte (e.g. UTF-8 as in your case I assume) as "binary" instead of text. I have no problem using BSD grep 2.5.1 and GNU grep 3.3. But it is annoying that shell scripts with grep commands to search Unicode files/input aren't portable.